# Can I feed spoofed video to sites like omegle.com that require a connected camera?

Tags: macos, video, web-browser, webcam

Sites like omegle.com want video from my connected camera, but I don't 
have one. How can I feed omegle.com (a Flash app) a spoofed video feed 
(eg, a static picture, mp4 file, etc?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CamTwist](http://allocinit.com/index.php?title=CamTwist) creates "pseudo-video" devices for lots of different things, so you could display your desktop or any subset of it, or other content you choose. CamTwist's feature set is likely very similar to Ryan Sharp's suggestion for ManyCam.

Comment: Score! Can it do audio too, or is that a separate app?

Comment: Mmmm. I don't entirely remember. IIRC I used Soundflower for streaming computer audio.

Answer (score 2):

[iGlasses](http://ecamm.com/mac/iglasses) is one way to do this. It shows up as a camera on websites, and you can play a video or show an image by dragging it into the effects tab.

Comment: http://ecamm.com/mac/iglasses

Answer (score 0):

Theres a free application called ManyCam, I've used it on Facebook and ChatRoulette to display a picture or movie file instead of my iSight.

Comment: Good idea, but didn't install on my Mac, not sure why.