# How to send a looped video to video feed?

Tags: macos, webcam

I am having some trouble with my webcam on my Mac running Catalina.

I want to send a looped video of myself to the webcam feed so I can still seem present in meetings. So, like, when Chrome asks the computer for the webcam, I want to be in control of what goes there.

An ideal solution would be something I could run with python, free software would also be okay. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/ for related question about virtual cameras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) (OBS) is a free and open source video suite that is capable of cutting from a live feed to a pre-recorded source video.

In additional to OBS, you will need [obs-mac-virtualcam](https://github.com/johnboiles/obs-mac-virtualcam) to map the output to a virtual camera:

> Creates a virtual webcam device from the output of OBS. Especially useful for streaming smooth, composited video into Zoom, Hangouts, Jitsi etc. Like CatxFish/obs-virtualcam but for macOS.